# Car Bulbs: T10 W5W 501 what do numbers and letters actually mean?

Tags: lights, bulbs

As you know when replacing a bulb you normally check the bulb, the vehicle handbook or online to find out which bulb is required. In this question I will be using the T10 501 W5W Bulb as an example and hopefully, by answering this, it'll help me understand the letters and numbers across a range of different bulbs.

*Currently, I assume the following:*

- T10 is the size of the bulb? However, you can also have T10 bulbs in the home or office which are completely different.
- 501 is the type bulb?
- W5W is Wedge 5 Watts?

Answer (score 5):

[image: W5W Bulb]

### T10

Refers to tubular glass, 10 mm diameter, according to this [forum post](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?403078-Why-are-the-smaller-w5w-t10-wedge-bulbs-more-expensive-than-the-bigger-t10-wedge-bulb&s=98573f3a0a72c068f267b8625dd19fa9&p=4675912&viewfull=1#post4675912).

---

### W5W

The W5W defines the bulb "category", which is the standardized filament lamp design, as explained in [ECE Regulation 37](http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/trans/main/wp29/wp29regs/R037r7e.pdf).

There is no explicit mention of the first "W" referring to "Wedge", but all bulb categories that start with a "W" share the same wedge-style base in the linked document.

Incidentally, W3W and W5W have the same dimensions, the former rated for 3 W output, the former rated for 5 W.

[image: W5W Table]

---

### 501

I couldn't find any reference to 501, but the bulb "type" is plausible.

The document distinguishes between "category" and "type":

> **2.1.1. Definition of "category"**
>   The term "category" is used in this Regulation to describe different basic design of standardised filament
>   lamps. Each category has a specific designation, as for example: "H4",
>   "P21W", "T4W", "PY21W"or "RR10W".
>
> **2.1.2. Definition of "type"**
>   Filament lamps of different "types" are filament lamps within the same category which differ in such essential respects as:
>
> 2.1.2.1. Trade name or mark (Filament lamps bearing the same trade name or mark but produced by different manufacturers are considered as
>   being of different types. Filament lamps produced by the same
>   manufacturer differing only by the trade name or mark may be
>   considered to be of the same type);
>
> 2.1.2.2. Bulb design and/or cap design, in so far as these differences affect the optical results;
>
> 2.1.2.3. Rated voltage;
>
> 2.1.2.4. Halogen.

Comment: I think 501 could be a UK or EU thing only because looking at https://www.eurocarparts.com/interior-bulbs they have many different codes that I can not find on Wikipedia or US based websites.